# Unpredictable System.DllNotFoundException

Tags: c#, dll, visual-studio-2015

I downloaded a package from SourceForge, [PlanEph](https://sourceforge.net/p/planeph/wiki/eph-vsop87.htm/), which has 64 and 32 bit DLLs for C#. I got the 32 bit included C# demo to work by putting the DLL in my bin/Debug directory (I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Community) and adding the DLL as a reference.

Then I tried to make my own version of the demo in a separate solution, and got the System.DllNotFoundException. Various experimentation lead me to believe I can't have two identical namespace names anywhere in my Visual Studio installation, so I erased everything and started over.

I made a directory C\GJAbin, put the DLL in it, and added it to the system Path variable. I also put a helloWorld type program in that dir and executed it from the command line to verify the directory really was in the path. Then I recreated the demo solution, added the DLL as a resource, and built the solution "successfully". Then I ran it and got the System.DllNotFoundException.

So I can't understand why the DLL is being found when compiling but not at run time.

Comment: It could be a matter of .net framework version, you should check that your new project .net framework version is identical or higher than the package version

Comment: If the .net framework version were wrong, it would never have worked. Since it worked once, I believe the framework version is OK. Also, Visual Studio was reinstalled this year.

Answer (score 0):

Go to project settings, go to "publish" tab and on the top most button (labeled something like "application files"). Chose "Show all files" checkbox if you don't see your DLL. Set the DLL's publish status to "Include" (NOT "Include (Auto)"!!) and publish it again.

Now the DLL should be inside the publish folder.

Comment: Sorry, but your description isn't specific enough for me to find the checkbox you are describing. Please understand I know more about astronomy (which is the topic of the program) than Visual Studio.

Comment: Right click on you project -> properties -> Target framework

Comment: Sagi Levi, target framework is 4.5.2. My understanding is that if the target framework of my program >= target of DLL I should be OK. And as I said, it worked once, and that was yesterday.

Comment: Also, the programs will be for my own use so publishing them to make them available to others isn't important to me.

Comment: Waka, I found the menu you meant, Projects tab at top of VS window -> Demo32 properties.... I did as you suggested, built the solution, and had the same problem

Answer (score 0):

> So I can't understand why the DLL is being found when compiling but not at run time.

Locating the assembly at compile time is done differently (by MSBuild) than at runtime (by the CLR).

At compile time, MSBuild has specific search paths that it knows about, or in most cases like this, there will be something in your project file telling MSBuild where to look for the file.  Usually the `<Reference>` has a `<HintPath>`.

At runtime, the CLR will attempt to find the assembly from its own set of well-known paths.  It will look in your app's config file (if applicable), then in the Global Assembly Cache (GAC), then in your app's root directory.  Much more detail on this is available [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx7xezcf(v=vs.110).aspx).

You can tell MSBuild to copy the reference to your build output directory (usually the same as your app root directory when running).  In VS, you can do this by selecting the reference and looking at the Properties tool window (or press <kbd>F4</kbd> by default).  Set the CopyLocal state to True.  In the project file, this will add a `<Private>True</Private>` on the `<Reference>`.

You can also add the assembly to the GAC using the `gacutil` tool, but this does make it harder if you want to share your app with others.  Usually it's preferable to keep a copy in your app root directory.

If it's still not working, you can also see the log for how the runtime is trying to find this assembly.  The `fuslogvw.exe` tool in the Windows SDK (you can run it from the VS command prompt and it will be on the %PATH%) allows you to enable logging for assembly loads.  You do need to be able to run this as an administrator to configure the setting.

[image: Settings from fuslogvw]

As you can see in the screenshot, you can either log the results in the exception (so that you can see it while debugging), or you can log it to a file on disk (so you can see it whenenver).

Comment: I checked the Copy Local and it was already true. I found that the dll was present in my ...\Projects\Demo32\Demo32\bin\Debug so just to be sure, I got rid of it and ran build again. Sure enough, there was a fresh copy of the dll in ...\bin\Debug. I'll look at fuslogvw a little later.

Comment: So I tried the logging to a file, and got a .pdb file, but don't know how to view that kind of file.

Comment: If you set a custom log path (which should be a folder) you should get the right files there.  Personally, I use the exception text and look at it in the debugger.  *.pdb files are the debugging symbols for your executable, they're not the log file you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be an unfortunate interaction among the way the author chose names and the way Visual Studio displays information and error messages. The author created a c# dll Astronomy.PlanEph32.dll containing a namespace PlanEph32, which which was really just a wrapper for the c dll PlanEph32.dll. So all the error messages about not being able to load PlanEph32.dll were referring to not finding the c dll; the c# dll was being found just fine.